# Matplotlib: common color map for 2 scatter plots within the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have bi-variate time-series stored in `2D Numpy arrays`. I would like to plot both channels of the series on the same plot. Each series should be represented by a line which is colored according to the channel. On top of these lines, I want to plot the points of the series as dots. These should be colored according to values in a second `2D Numpy array` of the same shape. My question is: how to set a color-map for the dots in a range that is common to both channels?

I managed to get lines of different colors and dots for each series with a double call of `plt.plot()` and `plt.scatter()` with something like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Bivariate time-series of length 10
nchannel, length = 2, 10
array_series = np.random.random((nchannel, length))
array_colors = np.vstack([np.repeat(0, length), np.repeat(1, length)])

colormap = 'jet'
plt.plot(np.arange(length), array_series[0,:])
plt.scatter(np.arange(length), array_series[0,:], c=array_colors[0,:], cmap=colormap)
plt.plot(np.arange(length), array_series[1,:])
plt.scatter(np.arange(length), array_series[1,:], c=array_colors[1,:], cmap=colormap)
```

This produces:
[image: Current output]

This is not the desired output because all dots are dark blue, so the distinction between 0 and 1 in `array_colors` is lost. I looked for something like replacing `plt.scatter(..., c=array_colors[i,:], cmap=colormap)` by `plt.scatter(..., c=array_colors, cmap=colormap)`. The latter, however, raises an error. Any idea to solve this would be welcome!

Comment: Can you show the expected output ? Or what is wrong with your snippet ?

Comment: @majpark after running you code i get randomly colored points

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I modified the array_colors definition in order to display the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can just use the flat version of the array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Bivariate time-series of length 10
nchannel, length = 2, 10
array_series = np.random.random((nchannel, length))
array_colors = np.random.random((nchannel, length))

x = np.arange(length)

plt.plot(x, array_series[0,:])
plt.plot(x, array_series[1,:])

xs = np.tile(x, nchannel)
plt.scatter(xs, array_series.flat, c=array_colors.flat)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameters `vmin` and `vmax`.

Pass as `vmin` the global minimum value, and as `vmax` the global maximum value. This will cause all calls to `scatter` to scale the values in the same range, producing a unified color scale.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nchannel, length = 2, 10
array_series = np.random.random((nchannel, length))
array_colors = np.vstack([np.repeat(0, length), np.repeat(1, length)])

colormap = 'jet'
vmin = np.min(array_colors)
vmax = np.max(array_colors)
x = np.arange(length)

plt.plot(x, array_series[0,:])
plt.scatter(x, array_series[0,:], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, c=array_colors[0,:], cmap=colormap)
plt.plot(x, array_series[1,:])
plt.scatter(x, array_series[1,:], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, c=array_colors[1,:], cmap=colormap)
```